# Integral of Exponent of L1 Norm of Linear Function

Tags: integration, exponential-function, determinant, absolute-value, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix with $m \geq n$ of full rank. I'm trying to solve for the integral
\begin{equation}
f(\vec{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(- \lVert A \vec{x} \rVert_1) \, d\vec{x}.
\end{equation}

In the case that $m = n$, I can solve the integral by taking the $RQ=A$ factorization of $A$, where $R$ is upper-triangular with positive diagonal and $Q$ is orthonormal:
\begin{equation}
R = \begin{bmatrix}
R_{1,1} & \dots & R_{1,n}\\
 & \ddots & \vdots \\
&& R_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad R_{i,i} > 0
\end{equation}
Then, via a change of variables $\vec{y}=Q\vec{x}$, we get that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(- \lVert A \vec{x} \rVert_1) \, d\vec{x}
=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(- \lVert R \vec{y} \rVert_1) \, d\vec{y}.
\end{equation}

Then, if $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{bmatrix}$,
by performing the integrals in order from 1 to $n$, the innermost integral (w.r.t. $y_1$) can be cleanly separated:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n R_{1,i} \, y_i \right\rvert\right) \, dy_1
&= \int_{-\infty}^{c_1} \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n R_{1,i} \, y_i \right) \, dy_1 + 
\int_{c_1}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n R_{1,i} \, y_i \right) \, dy_1 \\
&= \frac{2}{R_{11}}.
\end{align}
Repeating this process for $y_2, \dots, y_n$ then yields the answer
\begin{equation}
f(\vec{x}) = \frac{2^n}{ \prod_{i=1}^n R_{ii}}
\end{equation}

**Is there any way to generalize this to the case for $m>n$?**

One initial thought was that the QR transform seems to be applicable to rectangular matrices as well, but I couldn't find any information about whether RQ exists as well. If the RQ transform did exist, perhaps I could do the same thing but with $R \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ instead?

Comment: If $n>m$ then you will end up with some integrals of the form $\int_{\Bbb{R}}dy_i$ in your product which clearly diverges

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry, that was a typo. I meant $m>n$.

Comment: Sure, use the singular value decomposition. As long as you are integrating over your domain variables it will work out exactly the same as the eigenvalue decomposition that you did.

Comment: @NinadMunshi
I guess I am a bit confused though - how do you handle the fact that you are applying a change of variable going from $R^n$ to $R^m$?